# How Spring deserializes query params into Kotlin data classes?

Tags: spring, kotlin

Assume a Spring `@RestController` with a simple `@GetMapping` that accepts a `VenueQuery` dataclass as its parameter:

```kotlin
data class VenueQuery(
    val cityId: Long? = null,
    val countryIso: String? = null,
)

@RestController
open class VenueController {

    @GetMapping("/venues")
    open fun getVenues(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        venueQuery: VenueQuery
    ) { ... }
}
```

Runing the code as above, works "well". `GET /venues?cityId=1&countryIso=CZ` gets deserialised into `VenueQuery(cityId=1, countryIso="CZ"}`.

However, annotating the venueQuery function argument with `@RequestParam` causes the same request to be rejected with `BAD_REQUEST "Missing required parameter 'venueQuery'"`. This makes sense, but renders the former case even more confusing.

After searching for quite some time I still can't answer the following questions:

1. Where can I find a documentation that describes this behavior in more detail? I.e. any reference I could point to instead of relying on a one-time observation?
2. Is the first case even an expected behavior?
3. How does spring knows it should populate the `venueQuery` argument with query params, but not the `request` and `response` params? Does it infer by its types of servlet request/response?
4. Generally I struggle to find any documentation (not a "how to" but *documentation*) about how the Spring annotations and principles apply in Kotlin. Are there any notable sources?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score -2):

> 2. Expected behavior?

Yes.

> 3. How does spring knows it should populate the venueQuery argument with query params?

By its type. Try two of `VenueQuery` and see what happens.

> 4. Generally I struggle to find any documentation...

Unless the behavior is markedly different, there’s no special mention for Kotlin. As for “notable sources”, I’ve always found the answers I’m looking for in their source code. Grab a cup of coffee and fire up a debugger, you’ll too.